# How to assign different pair of sg to multiple ec2 instances terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, aws-security-group

I have a module for ec2 in which I created 8 instances and a different module for 8 different sg.
Now I want to assign 2 or 3 sg to an ec2 instance. So that each ec2 are having different sets of SGs.

I am able to assign the same SGs to all ec2 but not different SGs through module thing.

Can you help me with this..?

```
module "ec2" {
  source           = "../../euc-terraformcontrol-compute" 
  ami_id           =  "${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 0)},${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 1)},${element(split(",", 
  var.ami_id), 2)},${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 3)},${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 4)},${element(split(",", 
  var.ami_id), 5)},${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 6)},${element(split(",", var.ami_id), 7)}" 
  instance_count   = "${element(split(",", var.instance_count), 0)}"   
  root_volume_size = "${element(split(",", var.root_volume_size),0)}"
  subnet           = "subnet-01f72b25d394c4a3b,subnet-02aa0eeb3e901dea8,subnet-05a7668477dbbca72" 
  iam_instance_profile  = "${element(split(",", var.iam_instance_profile),0)}"  
  security_group  = "${element(split(",", module.security_groups.security_group_04_id), 0)},${element(split(",", module.security_groups.security_group_05_id), 1)}"   instance_type  = "${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 0)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 1)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 2)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 3)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 4)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 5)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 6)},${element(split(",", var.instance_type), 7)}"   
  instance_name  = "${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 0)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 1)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 2)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 3)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 4)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 5)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 6)},${element(split(",", var.instance_name), 7)}"
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the code in it is runnable? Your question should aim to include a [mcve] that can be ran by others that exhibits the behaviour you are seeing (either errors or does something that you don't want and have explained what is different from your expected output).

Answer (score 0):

The question begs one of abstraction. How far do you want to layer your abstractions?  The more you trying to pile your abstraction into a single call of a module the more complex your implementation becomes and harder it is to understand.  It is ok to break out the call of the of ec2 into a second call by security group. A really good way of thinking about it was introduced with [roles and profiles in puppet](https://web.archive.org/web/20190903192847/https://www.craigdunn.org/2012/05/239/).  Your ec2 module is like a profile.  Every time you call the ec2 module with a different set of parameters it is a new role.

You didn't post the module so it is hard to provide a specific answer, but with all the comma splits, it looks like you are creating arrays through strings. This makes it really hard to read and understand without tearing it apart. Take a look at some of the more [complex types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#complex-types) in terraform like map, list or object.  The language has built in functionality for processing these types.

You could have a map of security groups and a list of objects of the instances you are trying to create along with additional information you were passing in separately like root_volume_size, amd_id.  Each object could have the name of the security group which makes to your map of security groups. (See how all this abstraction becomes tedious to explain?)

Though in your instance I still recommend making a second call to the ec2 module.  You can even support count or for_each on modules now.  So perhaps you need to tear apart the subsets and create the security groups separately. Pass the SGs into the subnet creation module.